# How can I change git origin to a specific branch?

Tags: git, pull

I've cloned a specific branch at GitHub (3.x), but origin was automatically set to a different branch (2.x).

I only want to work on the 3.x branch (never the 2.x branch). I'd rather use git pull origin than git pull origin/3.x.

What's the best way to change the default pull location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, there's no way to have "git pull origin" work to pull the 3.x branch because it's not the default branch of the remote repo.

After some experimentation, the best solution turned out to be this (issued from the parent directory):

```
git clone -b 3.x --single-branch  git@github.com:user/reponame.git your_subdirectory
```

This prevents the other branch(es) from being cloned, and sets things up so "git pull" by itself, automatically pulls from the remote 3.x branch.

It also eliminates the potential errors with "git pull origin" or "git diff origin" (which would reference the default 2.x branch at the remote). Those commands don't work unless you reference the specific branch you've cloned.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand, you're trying to change your `origin/branch` url but no need. Just check two different approaches for your issue.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/somegreatpath/somegreatproject.git
$ cd somegreatproject
```

Check what branch you are using at this point:

```
$ git branch    
* 2.x
```

Check out the branch you want

```
$ git checkout -b 3.x origin/3.x
 Branch 3.x set up to track remote branch 3.x from origin.
 Switched to a new branch '3.x'
```

Confirm you are now using the branch you wanted:

```
$ git branch    
* 3.x
  2.x
```

If you want to update the code again later, run `git pull`:

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

And also you can change the `origin`. Firstly, check current remote url:

```
$ git remote -v
* origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
* origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Set new url

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Verify that the remote URL has changed.

```
$ git remote -v    
* origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORYUSERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
* origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORYUSERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Hope, this is help!

Comment: I'd prefer to use SSH. Does this work?

   git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/reponame.git/3.x

Comment: It should. If you have access with SSH in your client, you can do whatever you want with SSH.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I think origin can only refer to a repo, not to a branch in a repo.

Comment: Oh, my misunderstanding! I get it now. `origin` keyword just takes url place. Url does contain branches. If you want to push or pull from spesific branch, you also need to use origin + `some_branch`